# KD-Tree points are repeating and giving me the wrong output

Tags: java, processing, binary-search-tree, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I (tried) implementing a KD-Tree in Processing/Java and followed the logic that I've seen in dozens of posts and the wikipedia article, but I must've done something wrong since the output looks like this:
[image]

Instead of this: [image]

Clearly something is off since nodes are repeating and doesn't look like the Wikipedia Tree at all.

Here is my buildKDTree function:

```
  public Node buildKDTree(List<Point> pointList, int depth){

    int size = pointList.size();
    int axis = depth % 2;
    Node newNode = new Node();

    if(pointList.size() == 1)
    {
      System.out.print("I am a leaf \n");
      System.out.print("Size of list:  " + pointList.size() + "\n");
      System.out.print("Point:  " + pointList.get(0) + "\n");
      newNode.point = pointList.get(0);
      newNode.left = null;
      newNode.right = null;
      System.out.print("Node Point:  " + newNode.point + "\n");
      return newNode;    
    }

    if(size <= 0)
    {
      return null;
    }
    if(axis == 0)
    {
      //sort by x
      System.out.print("Sorting by X \n");
      Comparator<Point> com = new xComp();
      Collections.sort(pointList, com);
    }
    else if(axis == 1)
    {
      System.out.print("Sorting by Y \n");
      Comparator<Point> com = new yComp();
      Collections.sort(pointList, com);
    }
    int median = size/2;
    //System.out.print("Median is: " + points.get(median) + " \n");
    List<Point> beforeMedian = pointList.subList(0, median);
    List<Point> afterMedian = pointList.subList(median, size);

    newNode.point = pointList.get(median);
    newNode.left = buildKDTree(beforeMedian, depth + 1);
    newNode.right = buildKDTree(afterMedian, depth + 1);
    return newNode;
  }
```

My KD Tree class, Node class, and Point class:

```
class KDTree{
  Node root;

  public KDTree()
  {
    root = null;
  }

}

class Node{
  Node left;
  Node right;
  Point point;

  Node(Point _p, Node l, Node r){
    point = _p;
    left = l;
    right = r;
  }

  Node(Node l, Node r){
    left = l;
    right = r;
  }

  Node(){
    left = null;
    right = null;
    point = null;
  }

  Node(Point _p)
  {
    point = _p;
    left = null;
    right = null;
  }

  void setPoint(Point _p)
  {
    point = _p;
  }
}

class Point {

   public PVector p;
   boolean isNearestNeighbor = false;
   boolean isSearchLocation = false;

   public Point( float x, float y ){
     p = new PVector(x,y);
     isNearestNeighbor = false;
     isSearchLocation = false;
   }

   public Point(PVector _p0 ){
     p = _p0;
   }
}
```

How i'm printing the tree:

```
public void printLevelOrder(Node root)
 {
   if(root == null )
   {
     return;
   }
   Queue<Node> q =new LinkedList<Node>();
   q.add(root);
   while(true)
   {
     int nodeCount = q.size();
     if(nodeCount == 0)
     {
       break;
     }

     while(nodeCount > 0)
     {
       Node node = q.peek();
       System.out.print("("+node.point + ")");

       q.remove();

       if(node.left != null)
       {
         q.add(node.left);
       }

       if(node.right != null)
       {
         q.add(node.right);
       }

       if(nodeCount > 1)
       {
         System.out.print(", ");
       }
       nodeCount--;
     }
     System.out.println();
   }
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated! I've been looking at this for hours so maybe I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than providing some hints on what is likely going wrong, I'd like to suggest some steps to solving this issue yourself:

1. break the `buildKDTree` method into several smaller methods performing much smaller functions (e.g. build leaf, sort sublists etc.)
2. unit test each one to make sure it does exactly what you expect
3. unit test the whole function using simple cases moving to more complex cases
4. if any of those unit tests behave in an unexpected manner, use an interactive debugger to find out what is going
5. if you can't understand why something is behaving in a certain way, as a question on SO about that case
6. finally, once everything is behaving correctly, apply to a realistic case

This may take a little longer but you'll learn a lot more in the process.

Comment: Alright I’ll try doing that, though i’m on a time constraint. Is it something obvious i’m overlooking?

Comment: @22pac yes there's something obvious that you're overlooking

Comment: Unless there's more things that I haven't caught, I figured out that it was because I was doing this:    List<Point> afterMedian = pointList.subList(median, size); 

instead of doing this: List<Point> afterMedian = pointList.subList(median+1, size);

Comment: Yes that's the main issue.